# Google realtime api - accessing arrays inside a collaborative list

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

So I want to have a collaborative list object in which I store other lists, such as:

```
var tasks = model.createList();
tasks.pushAll([['Do', 'Buy', 'go'], ['1', '23', '44', '21']]);
```

My question is: how can I access those elements? Normally, something like tasks[i][j] would work but in the case of the realtime api it does not. Of course I can use the .asArray() method, however it is of no use to me when I want to add something to the specific array inside that list object.

EDIT: Ok, so you can get them with for example: `Tasks.get(i)[j]`But how can new elements be added inside of a specific array? `tasks.get(i).push('something')` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
var dumbList = tasks.get(i).slice();
```

will get you a copy of the normal (non-collaborative) array you've put there. You can change it and then set the value back in the collaborative array to put the new version in your document.

```
dumbList.push('new item');
tasks.set(i, dumbList);
```

that will trigger a ValuesChangedEvent on `tasks`.

Comment: And it's important to remember that `dumbList` is *not* a collaborative list, so the entire new value will be pushed to the server, changes from multiple users won't be merged, etc, etc. I hate saying this, but the shortest answer to the OP's question is 'rearrange your data model so you don't have to'.

Answer (score 0):

Since `model.createList()` returns a [CollaborativeList](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/reference/gapi.drive.realtime.CollaborativeList) class, the `get`method should do the trick (as you indicated). `push` should still be able to work as it will add an item at the end of the list. Another method you can use other than push would be the `insert`, but you'll have to specify at what index it will be added.

Also, please check out the [Data Modeling Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/realtime/advanced-model) as it contains ways to design efficient and correct data models for using Realtime API.

Comment: Sure, I can add elements to the tasks array but not to the specific array inside. When I do tasks.get(i).push('something') I get 'object is not extensible' error.